# show html text message in Json set response popup

Tags: magento-1.9

After complete the Ajax request I am getting a popup. I need below text in html format but it is showing as it is. I need link text with html format.

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')->setBody('Please click here <a href="#">link</a> to run the import process');
```

Comment: Please share the ajax code that you are using, also check the dataType parameter in your ajax request, if it's not set then set it to dataType:"html"

Comment: I am not using any ajax code. I am using observer in magento and after complete the request I want to send the message in html format in popup

Answer (score 0):

generally popups dont support links and html. You will have to send the response to trigger a js function and in that js function , using the returned response, you can either show some popup OR populate the desired html in a preset div OR add a styled popup control that supports html and show your desired html content in it.